# How to create a hier block with variable number of blocks?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I want to implement a hier block that acts as a selector and works with time interval. I have implemented this block for two inputs with basic gnu-radio blocks. However, it is very time-consuming for 8, 16, or 32 inputs as you may acknowledge. Can I implement this block as a hier block so that a user can implement it easily only by selecting the number of inputs and switching time? If not, how can I achieve that?

To be clear, I add my own implementation that uses basic GNU Radio blocks.

[image: selectorWithBasicBlocks]